# Configuring remember-me in spring security

Tags: spring-security, remember-me

How can i configure remember-me service in spring security.Am using spring3.0 +hibernate3+ struts2.I have tried as below.

login.jsp

```
<input type="checkbox" name="_spring_security_remember_me"/>remember-me
```

applicationContext-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:s="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">



    <description>SpringSecurity安全配置</description>

    <!-- http安全配置 -->
    <s:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" >
        <s:intercept-url pattern="/css/**" filters="none" />
        <s:intercept-url pattern="/img/**" filters="none" />
        <s:intercept-url pattern="/js/**" filters="none" />

        <s:intercept-url pattern="/account/user!save*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_修改用户')" />
        <s:intercept-url pattern="/account/user!delete*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_修改用户')" />
        <s:intercept-url pattern="/account/user*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_浏览用户')" />
        <s:intercept-url pattern="/account/role!save*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_修改角色')" />
        <s:intercept-url pattern="/account/role!delete*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_修改角色')" />
        <s:intercept-url pattern="/account/role*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_浏览角色')" />

        <s:form-login login-page="/login.action" default-target-url="/" authentication-failure-url="/login.action?error=true" />
        <s:logout logout-success-url="/" />
        <s:remember-me/>
    </s:http>

    <!-- 认证配置, 使用userDetailsService提供的用户信息 -->
    <s:authentication-manager erase-credentials="false">

        <s:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <s:password-encoder hash="plaintext" />
        </s:authentication-provider>
    </s:authentication-manager>

    <!-- 项目实现的用户查询服务 -->
    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="net.top.system.service.account.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />
</beans>
```

But no use at all.What else i need to configure in my application.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make an application that is already secured with Spring, needed to add the following to the XML:

```
<sec:http authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
       <sec:form-login/>
    <sec:custom-filter … />

    <sec:remember-me 
        data-source-ref="dataSource"
        user-service-ref="userDetailsService"/>
</sec:http>
```

Note that using “data-source” is not a "must", but it actually declares that you want to use a JDBC persistent token. (In this case, Spring works with PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.) Of course the data source bean has to be declared in the XML.

As [documented by Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#remember-me) , a table names persistent_logins has to exist in the DB.

The “userDetailsService” is a ref to the UserService bean, where the users and passwords are declared. It can be in the XML or point to the DB as well.

In run time, Spring creates a Cookie called SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE( ) . It is seen with the “JSESSION” Cookie. It we delete the JSESSION (meaning we open a brand new session, just like reopen the browser) the “remember me” cookie remembers the last login, and creates a new JSESSION.

HTH :-)